# css on mock button displays differently in development and production

Tags: .net, css, internet-explorer

I am using css to style a hyperlink to make it look like a button. This is a .net site.

```
a.pretend
{
display:inline-block;
border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-bottom:1px solid #999999;
border-right:1px solid #999999;
background-color:#E7F3F1;
padding:3px 8px;
color:Black;
text-decoration:None;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Viewing pages with mock buttons on them on my development machine using IE 9.0 they have a background color as set.

Publish the site to a production server on the local network, view the site from my development machine using the same browser, the background-color does not appear.

Any ideas? It's driving me nuts. (And please don't say use a different browser - it's an intranet - so I'm stuck with IE).

DocType is XMTML1.0 Transitional

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you inspected the rendered HTML to see if there is any difference in how it's being rendered?  Or used the developer tools in IE9 to trace the styles?

Comment: Do you have a link to your page?

Comment: Sorry, page is on an intranet. Yes have checked the html to see how it is being rendered. It is identical. It just says:

<a href="#" class="pretend">My Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

Cross-browser inline-block:

```
display:inline-block;
display: -moz-inline-stack;
*display:inline;
zoom:1;
```